# Why is jquery-ui-core enqueueing in my footer instead of the header?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, jquery-ui

This is what I'm using to make sure that I have jquery-ui-core available:

```
if (!is_admin()) add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'zg_load_scripts');
function zg_load_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script("jquery-ui-core");
}
```

I also tried `wp_enqueue_script("jquery-ui-core", null, null, false, false);` in a vain attempt to force it into the header. No dice. What's going on here?

Answer (score 8):

Why do you need it in the header?

It's enqueuing in the footer because when it was registered it was set to enqueue in the footer.

In `wp-includes/script-loader.php`:

```
$scripts->add( 'jquery-ui-core', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui.core.js', array('jquery'), '1.8.12' );
$scripts->add_data( 'jquery-ui-core', 'group', 1 );
```

The second line forces it to load in the footer. You could deregister the script, then re-enqueue it in the header:

```
<?php
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'zg_load_scripts');
function zg_load_scripts(){
    if( is_admin() ) return;
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-ui-core' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-core', site_url(  '/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui.core.js' ), array('jquery'), '1.8.12' );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Christopher. The missing link for me was `wp-includes/script-loader.php`. That's some good info there. You mention that it's being registered to enqueue in the footer, but where do you see that? I'm looking for `wp_register_script()` there but only see direct calls on the `$scripts` object.

Comment: Interestingly, as soon as I `wp_enqueue_script()` some other (custom) script and mark jquery-ui-core as a dependency, jquery-ui-core is popped to the header!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if the script loader thing matters -- it says it's for admin only, but it hooks into wp_default_scripts which isn't an admin-only thing.  Awesome that it works if you enqueue another as a dependency.  I suppose that's because the other script is in the header and WordPress puts ui-core above it.  Less work than my solution.

Comment: You should post what you did as an answer, by the way.  And mark this as accepted so other folks who have the same question can figure it out.